# Python decorated exception cant be excepted

Tags: python, exception, decorator

I used a decorator class to decorate an Exception, but, it seems that,  the exception seems to be unable to be excepted with the exact exception class. Use functools.update_wrapper to update the decorator class doesn't work either.

```
class ClsDecor(object):

    def __init__(self,cls):
        self.cls=cls
        self.counter=0

    def __call__(self,*args):
        self.counter+=1
        return self.cls(*args)

@ClsDecor
class Err(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
      Exception.__init__(self)

try:
    raise Err()
except Err as e:
    print 'catched'
except Exception as e:
    print 'Not catched'
```

Comment: Have you tried deriving the decorator from `Exception`?

Comment: thanks, tried, doesnt work.

Comment: After `@ClsDecor`, `Err` is an an *instance* of `ClsDecor`. `Err()` returns an instance of the initial `Err` class (whose name gets overwritten by the decoration). There's now an obvious type mismatch between `Err` and the instance returned from `Err()`. The type is actually `Err.cls`.

Comment: Thanks, yes, Err.cls would work, is there any kind of wrap tool to fix this?

Comment: And, in the default except, when I catch the exception, the type of it is <class '__main__.Err'>.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, method `__call__` should be:

```
def __call__(self, *args):
    return self.cls(*args)
```

Your code will raise an error inside `__call__` and brought you directly to `print 'Not catched'`, this is the first level error. After fixing this error, you'll reach the second level error of type mismatch, which is well-explained in comment by dhke. Basic idea is that `Err` is actually type `ClsDecor` after `@ClsDecor`, but you return an instance of raw type `Err` in `__call__`, which is obvious not matched with `except Err`. You can easily use an decorator to archive your purpose like:

```
def err_dec(Cls):
    class NewErr(Exception):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.err = Cls(*args, **kwargs)
return NewErr

@err_dec
class Err(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        Exception.__init__(self)
```

Updated for requirement in comment:

```
def err_dec(Cls):
    class NewErr(Exception):
        c = 0
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            NewErr.c = NewErr.c + 1
            self.err = Cls(*args, **kwargs)
        def counter(self):
            return NewErr.c
    return NewErr

@err_dec
class Err(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        Exception.__init__(self)

try:
    Err()
    Err()
    raise Err()
except Err as e:
    print e.counter()
    print 'catched'
except Exception as e:
    print 'Not catched'
```

Comment: thanks, my original purpose was trying to make a counter decorator for some of the exceptions, so after processing, I can get a counter of how many this kind of ignorable errors have be encountered.

Comment: You can checkout the updated part of my answer :-) Hope that could be helpful.

Comment: Thank u, u helped a lot, and , finally I used metaclass to modify the new class name to make the exception matches the original name. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

The problem does not lie in the decoration. Maybe the decoration confuses you, but that's not the problem.

You need to realize what `Err` is. Decorator works like a normal definition, but then you apply the decorator to the object before assigning to the name. That is it's equivalent to:

```
class Err(Exception):
def __init__(self):
  Exception.__init__(self)
Err = ClsDecor(Err)
```

Now `Err` is a `ClsDecor` instance, and when raising it you're calling the instance (and not the class), you will be calling `ClsDecor.__call__` (and not `ClsDecor.__init__`). It's there the fault occurs as you there try to call `self.cls` with an argument (`args`), but `self.cls` is `Err` which does not take any additional arguments (besides the `self`).

You would have seen this if you've printed the error in the default `except` clause. It's a good idea to print the error if you hit the default clause since it's often because you catch an unexpected exception:

```
except Exception as e:
    print 'Not catched', repr(e)
    raise
```

Or perhaps you shouldn't catch that at all - if not caught the exception and traceback will be printed anyway.

Comment: I tried to get the type info in the default except, it is <class '__main__.Err'>, so I got confused, I thought it should be considered as the type Err

Comment: @user3011780 It shouldn't be, I get a `TypeError` when I tried. Another thing you should consider is to not have a default `except` clause at all, normally this means that you get an exception you didn't expect and you wouldn't know how to handle it anyway and then you can often let that propagate out and result in a normal stack-trace error message from python. This shows where the error has occured.

Comment: TypeError should be caused by my previous post's typo error '*args' to 'args'.    thank u for your kind suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

With all u guys help, finally I got the solution like this:

```
    class ErrMetaClass(type):
        def __new__(mcls,cls_name,cls_parents,cls_attr):
            return super(ErrMetaClass,mcls).__new__(mcls, 
                   cls_attr['_cls'].__name__, cls_parents,cls_attr)

    def err_dec(cls):
        class NewErr(Exception):
            __metaclass__ = ErrMetaClass
            _cls=cls
            c=0
            def __init__(self):
                NewErr.c+=1
        return NewErr

    @err_dec
    class Err(Exception):
        def __init__(self):
          Exception.__init__(self)

    try:
        raise Err()
    except Err as e:
        print Err.c
    except Exception as e:
        print type(e)
```